# Storm Trident State Query While Update

Tags: state, apache-storm, trident

I have a storm trident topology wherein I have a simple hashmap state and a state query. Will the state query ever be called while the state is being updated?

Answer (score 0):

After some experimentation, I figure that updating the state whilst querying it is harmless because the state updates and queries appear to be ordered.